# E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper﹕ Failed to get contextual suggestions Android API 22

Tags: android-volley, searchview

I have a search action view on the action bar. On each search query I call the google image search api to get the JSON request. I am getting this error all the time I execute the search. I am being able to load the images in the NetworkImageView but I want to understand this error.

04-06 14:33:49.913     807-1134/? E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper﹕ Failed to get contextual suggestions.
04-06 14:33:49.913     807-1134/? E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper﹕ package name: com.example.gallery
04-06 14:33:49.914     807-1134/? E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper﹕ Error message: Disabled
04-06 14:33:50.954   1062-19581/? D/GCM﹕ Message class com.google.f.a.a.i

Comment: AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper is a data logger service that creates Data usage stats for system-wide apps. It seems it is failing coz of something.

Can you post your code and full stacktrace of crash?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, you might have forgotten to add

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="your_api_key"/>`

under the application tag of AndroidManifest.xml.